# What is the use of and how can one add favorites in TeXStudio side pane?

Tags: texstudio

I'm using TeXstudio. In the side pane where you can see structures and some symbols, there is tab called *Favorites*. What is it for? Can one add a command to it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have symbols you use often, you can add them to the favorites, by right-clicking on a symbol in one of the other tabs:

[image]

Click that, and the symbol shows up in favorites:

[image]